# SMS 2003 and WSUS on the Same Server?

Tags: wsus, sms

I'm dealing with a SMS 2003 SP3 server that is also running WSUS 3 and we're experiencing suspect behavior between the two.  Neither seems to be giving us the details we think we should be getting.  Has anyone heard of any issues or had any experience where the two have not played nice with each other?  Our plan is to seperate them moving each to a new server.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals SEVERAL folks out there having problems with SMS 2003 SP3 and WSUS 3 on the same machine.

I'd say if you can separate the two reasonably quickly and test it will potentially save you A LOT of time in the long run.

To word it another way... there are enough examples out there of other people having the same (or similar) problems as you to justify separating the two to see if that fixes the problem.

Good luck! :-)

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Seperating the two seems to be the smart way to go.